# add 3 to all integers in list without for loop c#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I want to plus 3 to all `list<int>` member without using for loop or foreach loop ? Can I do this in one line ?How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something *somewhere* is going to have to loop. You don't have to loop in *your* code, but something's going to have to.

I can't think of anything offhand which will modify all the elements in a list, but using LINQ you could create a *new* `List<int>` easily:

```
var plusThree = originalList.Select(x => x + 3).ToList();
```

or pre-LINQ (and slightly more efficient, but also more `List<T>`-specific):

```
var plusThree = originalList.ConvertAll(x => x + 3);
```

But both of these *will* be looping behind the scenes.

You could potentially create a projecting `IList<T>` implementation which *lazily* applied a projection (or possibly a bijection if you wanted to be really fancy)... but that would be significant amounts of work.

Comment: For really "pre-LINQ" you'd have to ditch the lambda.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Nope - you could still use the lambda expression when targeting .NET 2, so long as you've got a C# 3+ compiler. Hopefully the OP isn't still using Visual Studio 2005 :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the value in the list itself, so there is no other way then to do it in a for loop, unless you are allowed to make a new list, then you can use Linq (which will loop in it's own code).

`for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) list[i]+=3;`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (ofcourse it feels like writing foreach loop without actually writing it )

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(5);



        int k = 0;
        list.ForEach(delegate(int i) {  list[k++] = i+3; });



        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```